# Can a page on a website get a facebook access token?

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-opengraph

I'm fairly new to facebook development and I still get confused about the oAuth thing.
A client of mine asked me to show the latest posts, links and statuses of his facebook page to his website.

On the a php page on his website I'm creating a url

> "https://graph.facebook.com/".$clientFacebookPage."/posts?limit=1&access_token= xxx

In order to json decode it and display the info I want, but I don't know how to get an access token. I generated an access token with the graph explorer that is tied to my name as a facebook developer but that expires in 2 hours.

There are many thing that confuse me already and I hope you can point me towards a solution
I've read the documentation but everything revolves around users getting logged on your app and you app posting. So my questions are:

- Do I need to create an app to do a curl (requiring special permissions) using the http://graph.facebook/xxxx url?
- If so, does the adming of the facebook page need to authorize with the app?
- What do I need to do next? I can create a web page using the app id and secret. Does that mean that I can retrieve the info of the facebook page? How?
- I know that the page needs an auth token to curl the http://graph.facebook/xxxx page and retrieve the data needed. Where can I generate it? Does the webpage need to generate it, or do I have (as the app developer) acquire the token and write it to my php code?
- If I log out of the facebook, will the program/webpage stop functioning?

I hope I didn't confuse you.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic process for obtaining an access token for a Page is as follows:
1. Get a user access token for a User who is an admin of the Page
2. Using this User token, request graph.facebook.com/me/accounts and look for the correct Page ID in the list returned.
3. Grab the associated Page token from that ID
4. Use it to do Page stuff.

There is a newly launched Facebook docs guide which shows you how to obtain one of these access tokens in a step-by-step fashion:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-page/
Hopefully that guide should help you.

I will also answer your questions in order:

- Yes, you will need an app in order to generate access tokens to make API queries
- Yes
- This is in the guide linked above (start at the Getting Started if you need to create a way to get a User Access Token also)
- Again, see the guide above
- Yes, but you should follow the steps in [this guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/#step1) to generate a long-lived access token. Once you do that, any Page token you retrieve will last forever.

Comment: Thank you Matthew, I followed every step and I finally got to make it work. I have another question thought:

The documentation states that access_tokens will expire after 60 days.
What does the webpage owner (and facebook page admin) has to do?

I'm keeping the access_token to a database so I can retrieve it and show the data I want to irrelevant to facebook visitors. What if the token expires? Should I make a "hidden" page that gets an  access_token to replace the "current" in the database and have the admin logging in once per two months? Is that a legit solution?

Thank you again!